# Rendering a Rails partial on a jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I may be thinking of this all wrong but I've been trying to render a partial in a jQuery click function like so...

```
closeShow.click(function(){
    parentDiv.empty();
    parentDiv.html('<%= escape_javascript(render "sibling_div_partial") %>');
});
```

I've also tried using `.append` for the partial but the when I check the view in the browser, it comes up with just the text (i.e `<%= escape_javascript(render "sibling_div_partial") %>`) instead of the partial.

A little more infomration as to what I'm trying to accomplish.... I want to remove a div when the close button is clicked and then rebuild that div as a partial when a close button is clicked.

Am I conceptualizing this all wrong?

Comment: Do a response format js front the controller, and then create a js view with the escape_javascrit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were it me, I would probably go with a remote link in Rails, which makes a js-formatted request to your controller/action.

Once clicked, the remote link would hit the controller/action specified in the link path/url and then, in that controller action's js file you can run the appropriate JavaScript.

**The ERB/HAML View**

```
# home/index.html.erb 
<%= link_to 'Some Link', some_controller_path, remote: true %>
```

**The Controller**

```
# my controllers_controller.rb
def controller_action
  # do awesome controller stuff
end
```

**The Action's JS View**

```
# controller_action.js.erb 
$('parent-div').empty();
$('parent-div').html('<%= escape_javascript(render "sibling_div_partial") %>');
```

Comment: `# controller_action.js.haml ` - shouldn't that be erb?

Comment: LOL ... yes, if you use ERB and not HAML ... I hate ERB since it reminds me of ASP and makes cold shivers go down my spine ;) ... but you're right as his `escape_javascript` is using ERB. Will edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can render dynamically. Rendering happens in the controller, whereas javascript is all view (i.e. client-side).

You can try putting the partial in your template, and toggle visibility of parentDiv when clicked.